# How can I display a GeoTIFF with multiple bands on OpenLayers?

Tags: raster, openlayers, geotiff-tiff, image, netcdf

I have a NetCDF file including 1365 bands (when opening in QGIS for example). To display it on an online map like OpenLayers, I tried to export it as a GeoTIFF image. I read a solution here that suggests MapTiler to convert the file to Tile, but it does not work, since the file has more than one band!

Do you know any other way to display GeoTIFF on OpenLayers?

Comment: Not sure you can display GeoTIFF in any browser (without some extension), so not sure how you'll get a GeoTIFF to display natively in an OpenLayers client.  Are you really after a GeoTIFF solution, or would some way of viewing the NetCDF data itself work?

Comment: Actually I prefer to find a direct way for visualizing NetCDF, but as far as I understood it would be a more difficult task!

Comment: Would the WMS and other services of THREDDS http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/tds/ serve your needs?  I like its Godiva interface for browsing around time series of netcdf rasters.

Comment: I see either WMS or WCS as the solution here, depending on what you want to do with the data in OpenLayers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the WMS services provided by the [THREDDS Data Server](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/tds/), as long are your NetCDF data are [CF-Compliant](http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.7/cf-conventions.html). You can display the data in your browser using WMS-consuming clients like Leaflet, OpenLayers, ArcGIS or TerriaJS.

Here's a [cool example visualizing NetCDF data via WMS from THREDDS Data Server using Leaflet Time dimension](http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example13.html).  Try double clicking a point, then scroll down to see the time series plots underneath the map!

Installing THREDDS Data Server is now really easy also now that there is a [THREDDS Docker Container](https://hub.docker.com/r/unidata/thredds-docker/).